# How to prove that this infinite sum converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

$a_1,...,a_k$ are real numbers all bigger then $1$. Define the following sequence of numbers: 
 $$b_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{a_1^{n^2}+a_2^{n^2}+...+a_k^{n^2}}}$$ Show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n$ converges. I tried all the convergence tests that I know but none of them worked, and I have no other clue how to attack it. Can anyone please help?

Comment: What tests did you try?  Please show your work from these tries.

Answer (score 1):

Since $0\le b_n\le a_1^{-n}$, convergence follows from comparison with a geometric series.

Comment: wow, I'm an idiot. It is so simple. Thank you!